# executing these two codes after each other with an if statement

Tags: java, arrays, object, if-statement

```
if (m>1){

        if (x1>=0 || x1<0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the values of f(x1): \n");
            for (int i = Koef.length-2; i >=0; i--) { // gives the length of my row (m)
                for (int j =Koef[0].length-1; j>=0;j--) { //gives the length of my column (n).
                    Koef[0][j] = readInteger("Enter the values of your coeffecients: "
                                            +"f(x1), Coeffecient" +(j)+": "); // readInteger takes an input from the user
                }
                    System.out.println();
            }
        }
```

//MY PROBLEM is here
//I was trying to execute this code below too after the code above finishes, but somehow it never reaches to it

```
        if(x2>=0 || x2<0) {
            System.out.println("Now enter the value of f(x2):  \n");
            for (int i = Koef.length-2; i >=0; i--) { 
                for (int j =Koef[0].length-1; j>=0;j--) { 

                    Koef[1][j] = readInteger("Enter the value of coefficients: "
                                            +"f(x2), Coefficient" +(j)+": ");
                }
            }
        }
====================================================================
```

//This what happens in the testClass:

```
if (m==2) {
int n = 1+readInteger("Which polynomial degree do you want to enter for f(x1)?");
                int x1 = readInteger("please enter the value of x1:");
                polynom pol1 = new polynom (m,n,x1,0); //m-2 = array 0 & n +1 = polynomial degree of array 0
```

// m is first array, n is second array, x1 is the value of 1st polynomial x2 value of 2nd

```
int n = 1+readInteger("Which polynomial degree do you want to enter for f(x2)?");
                int x2 = readInteger("Please enter the value of x2:");
                polynom pol2 = new polynom (m,n,0,x2);
}
```

I already tried not to use the if statements, but I got as a print of f(x1) and f(x2) with the first given power and then got both results again with the 2nd given power.

What I want is: to get f(x1) with the first power (n) and f(x2) with the second power
Each, one time only.

I would be grateful if you can get me out of this predicament 
Thanks for any help :)

*EDIT*  part of the code for more clarification: 
TESTCLASS

```
public class MainMenu{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Do you want to calculate one or two polynoms?");
        int m = readInteger();

            if (m==1) {
                int n = 1+readInteger("Which polynom degree for f(x1), do you want to calculate?");
                int x1 = readInteger("Please enter the value of x1: ");
                pol1.eingabe();
                pol1.ausgabe();
            }

            else if (m==2) {
                int n = 1+readInteger("Which polynom degree for f(x1), do you want to calculate?");
                int x1 = readInteger("Please enter the value of x1: ");
                polynom pol1 = new polynom (m,n,x1,0);

                n = 1+readInteger("Which polynom degree for f(x2), do you want to calculate?");
                int x2 = readInteger("Please enter the value of x2: ");
                polynom pol2 = new polynom (m,n,0,x2);
                polynom pol3 = new polynom (m,n,x1,x2); //addition

                pol1.eingabe();
                pol2.eingabe(); 
                pol1.ausgabe();
                pol2.ausgabe();
                pol3.addieren(pol1, pol2);

            }
```

POLYNOMCLASS

```
public class polynom {

private int n; //number of Polynomial degree
private int m; //number of polynoms
private double[][] Koef;
private double x1;
private double x2;
public polynom (int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    m =a;
    n=b; 
    Koef = new double[m][n]; // create n arrays (n =6.. that means create 6 opening for coefficients)

    x1 =c;
    x2 =d;
}
public void eingabe() {
    if (m==1) {
        for (int i = Koef.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
            for (int j =Koef[0].length-1; j>=0;j--) {
                Koef[0][j] = readInteger("Enter the coeffecient values of f(x1) ein: " +(j) +": ");
            }
        }
    }
    //=========================================
    //=========================================
    if (m>1){

        if (x1>=0 || x1<0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the value of f(x1) : \n");
            for (int i = Koef.length-2; i >=0; i--) { 
                for (int j =Koef[0].length-1; j>=0;j--) {  
                    Koef[0][j] = readInteger("Give the value of"+"f(x1) , Coeffiecient" +(j)+": ");
                }
                    System.out.println();
            }
        }

        if(x2>=0 || x2<0) {
            System.out.println("Now, enter the values of f(x2) \n");
            for (int i = Koef.length-2; i >=0; i--) { 
                for (int j =Koef[0].length-1; j>=0;j--) {
                    Koef[1][j] = readInteger("Enter the coeffiecient values of "+"f(x2) ein, Koeffizient " +(j)+": ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the if statements? They appear to always be true?

Comment: I thought, it will take the first object and initialize x1 with a value and x2 with 0, printing f(x1) only, then it will take the second object and initialize x1 with 0 and and x2 with a value, printing the second if statement!!!

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: pls can u provide the full code snippet  so that we can understand where some weird variables are coming from

Comment: I just edited part of it, for more clarification..

Comment: What is the thought you have for the ifs " if (x1>=0 || x1<0)" this means true if it is bigger as 0, equals 0 or is smaller as 0 = always true

Answer (score 0):

Hey man I think it's about your syntax. 
I've tried your code myself and I got it running after I replaced readInteger with `Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);`
May check your class structure.
(Didn't make it pretty since I wanted to reproduce your error)

I checked in Debugger and the array had values of both your if-cases.
But check your loops the inner loop runs twice and overwrites the first value since your `Koef[1][j]` is hard in there.
Also in your case maybe it would be better to use double as input value instead of integer, since that will always round your values.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainMenu {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create an object that reads integers:
    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Do you want to calculate one or two polynoms?");
    int m = cin.nextInt();

    if (m == 1) {
        System.out.println("Which polynom degree for f(x1), do you want to calculate?");
        int n = 1 + cin.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the value of x1: ");
        int x1 = cin.nextInt();
        polynom pol1 = new polynom(m, n, x1, 0);
        pol1.eingabe();
        // pol1.ausgabe();
    }

    else if (m == 2) {

        System.out.println("Which polynom degree for f(x1), do you want to calculate?");
        int n = cin.nextInt();
        n += 1;
        System.out.println("Please enter the value of x1: ");
        int x1 = cin.nextInt();
        polynom pol1 = new polynom(m, n, x1, 0);

        System.out.println("Which polynom degree for f(x2), do you want to calculate?");
        n = cin.nextInt();
        n += 1;
        System.out.println("Please enter the value of x2: ");
        int x2 = cin.nextInt();
        polynom pol2 = new polynom(m, n, 0, x2);
        polynom pol3 = new polynom(m, n, x1, x2); // addition

        pol1.eingabe();
        pol2.eingabe();
        // pol1.ausgabe();
        // pol2.ausgabe();
        // pol3.addieren(pol1, pol2);
        cin.close();
    }
}
}


import java.util.Scanner;

public class polynom {

private int n; // number of Polynomial degree
private int m; // number of polynoms
private double[][] Koef;
private double x1;
private double x2;

public polynom(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    m = a;
    n = b;
    Koef = new double[m][n]; // create n arrays (n =6.. that means create 6 opening for coefficients)

    x1 = c;
    x2 = d;
}

public void eingabe() {
    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (m == 1) {
        for (int i = Koef.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = Koef[0].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                System.out.println("Enter the coeffecient values of f(x1) ein: ");
                Koef[0][j] = cin.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
    // =========================================
    // =========================================
    if (m > 1) {

        if (x1 >= 0 || x1 < 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the value of f(x1) : \n");
            for (int i = Koef.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
                for (int j = Koef[0].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the coeffecient values of f(x1) ein: ");
                    Koef[0][j] = cin.nextInt();
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        if (x2 >= 0 || x2 < 0) {
            System.out.println("Now, enter the values of f(x2) \n");
            for (int i = Koef.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
                for (int j = Koef[0].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the coeffiecient values of " + "f(x2) ein, Koeffizient ");
                    Koef[1][j] = cin.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cin.close();
}
}
```

--> Debugger

[image: Debugger - Array]

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code you create a matrix ( 2D array) for two vectors of coefficients - Koef[m][n]

However, your if statements ( x1>=0 || x1<0 and x2>=0 || x2<0) does not make any sense, so the are true always, You have two blocks of code inside this ifs.

In the blocks you read coefficients for 2 polynomials.
Your external for-loops are strange too, because if m==1 or m==2 your external for-loops will make only step and you set the coefficients either for one or two polynomials.

But if m>2, you will enter coefficients for the polynomials several times.

for example:
**m=10**
you will go to **if(m>1)** section

then in each of ifs (by x1 and x2)

you will need to enter coefficients in

```
for (int i = Koef.length-2; i >=0; i--)
```

9 times, because **Koef.length=10** 
you will enter coefficients in iterations by **i** from 8 to 0

You wrote that you don't get into the second if **(x2>=0 || x2<0)**

maybe you have big **m** and the first if waits for data more then one time?
you actually don't need an external for-loops, because you do the same operations in each iteration and rewrite the same coefficients many times

hope it will help